# Meaning of notation

Tags: normed-spaces

I came across this loss representation in caffe loss function ([here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/euclideanloss.html))

What does the notation mean ? I mean why are there 2 `2`s
$$
E = \frac{1}{2n} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \left| \left| \hat{y}_n - y_n       \right| \right|_2^2
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $2$ in the subscript refers to $2$-norm. $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$

The $2$ in the superscript refers to square as in $x^2=x.x$.

Together, we have

$$\|x\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$$

Comment: To the OP, this is to distinguish from the more general $p$-norm: $\|x\|_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$